# Pass state from one component to other component using global variable on ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After reading tons of other related questions here. I couldn't find my answer yet. I have improved my code and I believe that I am very close to a solution, still, I couldn't accomplish my goal.

I am a newbie to coding and react native. I want to build water reminder app and I have 2 main screens. The home screen is where I display current progress, how much water user drunk today. In settings, screen user types her age, weight and gender to determine water amount (sliderValue state) they should drink daily.

Then after defining the amount in the settings screen, I would like to use this amount in Home screen. Since I am a beginner and don't want to create complexities in my app.

I am looking for solutions without redux etc. Therefore I saw in other questions that I saw creating global variable would be ideal for me. 
I defined global.drinkAmount and set it to sliderValue state when the state is updated with componentDidUpdate. But I still get zero.

```
// HomeScreen.js

  state = {
    progress: 0,
    drunk: 0,
    open: false,
    goal: global.drinkAmount,
  };

render(){
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.drunk}>{this.state.drunk} / <Text style={styles.goal}>{this.state.goal}</Text></Text>
  </View>
}
```

```
//SettingsScreen.js

 global.drinkAmount = 0;
export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    age: "",
    weight: "",
    gender: "",
    sliderValue: 0
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.sliderValue !== prevState.sliderValue) {
      global.drinkAmount = this.state.sliderValue;
    }
  }
```

[image: Home Screen]

[image: Settings Screen]

Comment: How are you navigating between screens? How are you storing the amount of water if the app is closed and re-opened?

Comment: @Andrew I am using react navigation to navigate between screens. This seems silly to you but I am keeping it in the state. I thought water amount is stored/kept in memory inside state even after app is closed and re-opened. I am not using any server connection to store water amount.

Comment: State isn’t persisted so you will lose it when you close the app fully.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Then I need to use server and after using server I can get amount of water from server. Therefore my question wont be relevant anymore.

Comment: You don't need to use a server, you can handle it in the app.

Comment: @Andrew How can I do that?

Comment: @sinan local storage, indexing, something to that effect

Comment: Use AppState.nextAppState to detect when the app is closing(background/inactive), at which time you store values in "local storage" using AsyncStorage.setItem(). Then use AsyncStorage.getItem() when AppState.nextAppState becomes active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options for you to solve this. I think the simplest is to use `AsyncStorage` and navigation listeners to lifecycle events.

## AsyncStorage

AsyncStorage allows you to save strings so that they can be retrieved. Make sure you read the documentation about it, they have some good examples.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

You can set items into AsyncStorage in the following way

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

// note both key and value must be strings
_storeData = async (key, value) => {   
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
  }
}

_retrieveData = async (key) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

## Navigation lifecycle events

Navigation Listeners to lifecycle events allows you to see if a screen has come back into focus or not. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

There are four different events you can listen to:

- `willFocus` - the screen will focus
- `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
- `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
- `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

In your screens you can listeners to capture when the screen will come into focus or when it will blur. You can register the listener in componentDidMount and unsubscribe (which is important if you do not want memory leaks) in the componentWillUnmount.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    payload => {
      console.debug('willFocus', payload);
      // you could make function calls here to retrieve values from AsyncStorage
      // which could then update the values that you have in state.
    }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  if(this.willFocusSubscription) {
     this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could pass the values and functions between the screens. But I think this solution is quite straight forward and it means that you don't have to use `AppState` changes to capture values, as all your values will be updated and stored in AsyncStorage.